# "Impossible" error message in R for VennDiagram

Tags: venn-diagram

I keep getting an error message when trying to use `VennDiagram` in R. Below is my posted code:

```
draw.quintuple.venn(area1 = 578, area2 = 519, area3 = 212, area4 = 402, area5 = 172, n12 = 366, n15 = 97, n13 =149, n14 = 284, n23 = 103, n24 = 202, n25 = 125, n35 = 31, n34= 12, n45 = 27, n123 = 80, n124 = 161, n125 = 84, n134 = 8, n135 = 25, n145 = 20, n234 = 5, n235 = 24, n245 = 21, n345 = 1, n1234 = 5, n1345 = 21, n1245 = 16, n1235 = 0, n2345 = 0, n12345 = 0, category = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), lty = "blank", fill = c("skyblue", "pink1", "mediumorchid", "yellow", "orange"))
```

**Error:**

> ERROR [2018-07-09 13:37:19] Impossible: a11 <- n23 - a21 - a22 - a24 -
>   a26 - a29 - a30 - a31 produces negative area Error in
>   draw.quintuple.venn(area1 = 578, area2 = 519, area3 = 212, area4 =
>   402,  :    Impossible: a11 <- n23 - a21 - a22 - a24 - a26 - a29 - a30
>   - a31 produces negative area

What am I doing wrong?

I double checked and made sure the values are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this package is well documented. A look at the source code shows that the meaning of `nxxxxx` is not the obvious one. For instance `n135` means "how many elements belong to **at least** groups 1, 3 and 5". When you want to draw the diagram, the package calculates how many of those `n135` also belong to other groups (i. e., `n1235`, `n1345` and `n12345`) and substracts them. 
What seems to be happening here is that you interpret `n135` as "how many elements **only** belong to sets 1, 3 and 5" (that would have also been my guess). If you want to use those numbers directly, you should write:

```
draw.quintuple.venn(area.vector = c(578, 519, 212, 402, 172, 31, 97, 284, 366, 125, 103, 149, 12, 202, 27, 1, 25, 20, 161, 84, 24, 80, 8, 5, 21, 0, 21, 16, 0, 5, 0), category = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), lty = "blank", fill = c("skyblue", "pink1", "mediumorchid", "yellow", "orange"), direct.area = T)
```

[image: VennDiagram picture]

The order of the numbers is taken directly from the source code, I have not seen it documented. Let us call `a135` "how many elements **only** belong to sets 2, 3 and 5". With this in mind, the order would be:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a35, a15, a14, a12, a25, a23, a13, a34, a24, a45, a345, a135, a145, a124, a125, a235, a123, a134, a234, a245, a2345, a1345, a1245, a1235, a1234, a12345
```

If you prefer to use the `n135` notation, you would need to transform your data, so that `n135 = a135 + a1235 + a1345 + a12345`, and so forth. In your case, `n135 = 25 + 0 + 21 + 0 = 36`.

Although not part of the question, you can also use my `nVennR` package for a proportional representation. The order of the numbers is documented in the help and the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html), and you can also enter raw sets rather than numbers:

```
library(nVennR)
myV <- createVennObj(nSets = 5, sNames = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'), sSizes = c(0, 172, 402, 27, 212, 31, 12, 1, 519, 125, 202, 21, 103, 24, 5, 0, 578, 97, 284, 20, 149, 25, 8, 21, 366, 84, 161, 16, 80, 0, 5, 0))
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV, setColors = c("skyblue", "pink1", "mediumorchid", "yellow", "orange"), borderWidth = 0)
```

And the result:

[image: nVennR picture]